Seeking Advice on Tackling Real-Life ML Problem Interview Questions
I am currently preparing for interviews in machine learning and often encounter questions about solving real-world ML problems. I find these questions particularly interesting but challenging to approach systematically. I was wondering if you could share some guidance or strategies on how to effectively structure responses to such problems during interviews.

In real-world data science / machine learning, there is more than just building a model that has high accuracy. So in my point a view, a good answer is one that will partially cover all of the following points of the interviewer's question:

Problem statement: in real-world, you usually start here as you are likely going to be building a solution to a problem for someone (either internal stakeholders, clients, etc.). So you need to align with them what do they want (what target are you predicting, what metrics to optimise, data availability, etc.)
Data Loading: where the data lives, how you will ingest it, how far back does it go, can you get more?
Data Discovery: what EDA steps you will take to learn the data, and what actions will you take based on the following (handling missing values, skewed distributions, time series data, etc.)
Feature Engineering: are you going to need to create new features from existing data to better predict your target? Based on your EDA, are you going to transform the data?
Model Fitting: choice of modelling technique, feature selection based on technique used, model-tuning to optimise the hyperparameter space to improve the metric you are working towards
Model Validation: Will the model you build work in real-life aka will it generalise well to unseen data? Are the metrics you decided early on still good for the stakeholders/clients in all scenarios you have thought of.
Model Results: How are you going to share the model: through some results in slides, a report, through an app the users will interact with directly?
Model Deployment: How will the model be used by the stakeholders? Through a web app, ingesting numbers you provide periodically? How will the data be delivered continuously?

This is by far a non-exhaustive list, but in interviews where I had an open question about how I will tackle a data science / machine learning problem, I would touch all of the topics above. I beleeive this will show you have relevant experience and understand everything that goes into real-world data science / machine learning.
Note: this is a subjective question, so this answer is really my own opinion.
